# Adobe Acrobat Javascript Error: Value is unsupported

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue with a PDF (Adobe Acrobat) using custom trusted function. It works on my machine (go figure), possibly some permissions issue?

When the user hits a button the PDF it is supposed to save it as a JPEG to a known folder location.

The trusted function exists in the users folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Javascripts

```
var CustSaveAsJpeg = app.trustedFunction(
   function(d,p,f) //D=Document, p=path, f=filename
   {
      app.beginPriv();
      p= p.replace(/([^/])$/, "$1/");
      try{
         d.saveAs(p + f, "com.adobe.acrobat.jpeg");
      }catch(e){
         app.alert("Error During Save:" + e.toString());
      }
       app.endPriv();
   }
);
```

It is called like so:

```
var m = this.getField("ID").value;
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getSeconds();
var s = "/nas1/dfs/Shared/Departments/Saves/";
var f = m + "-" + n + ".jpeg";
if(typeof(CustSaveAsJpeg) == "function"){CustSaveAsJpeg(this,s,f);};
```

When i run it, I'm getting either obsolete function call, or value is unsupported Param: p.

- I don't think it is an issue with the folder\file path, it works on my machine
- I don't think it is a permissions issue (but it could be); the user can create/delete/modify files in that folder (acrobat executing this function under the local user?)
- If it matters, i have adobe acrobat Pro DC, whereas the user has the Acrobat DC (Free version)

Comment: The free Adobe Acrobat Reader DC can't export to image formats.

Comment: @joelgeraci - Would have been good if adobe documentation was a little more clear on that. If it is a 'fillable' form, is it possible to save with the form fields intact? The PDF has scripting that when opened it 'resets'

Comment: For current versions of Reader, yes, it can save form data. I'm not sure why you would have the form reset when it's opened though.